# How to get the NSError message in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nserror

I am having the method in my view controller as shown below:

```
- (void)parser:(PaymentTermsLibxmlParser *)parser encounteredError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog("error occured");
}
```

Here I need to show the Actual error message in the NSError in my alert can any one suggest how to get it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To get error message *only*, use:

```
NSString *msg = [error localizedDescription];
```

But for logging more details, use `%@` format, like:

```
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
```

Answer (score 46):

Normally you'll want to use `[error localizedDescription]` to get the text to show to the user.

Read the NSError documentation for more options.

For simple logging when developing, you can do `NSLog(@"Error: %@", error)`. (That will give you 'localizedDescription' and everything else on your log in Xcode.)

Answer (score 5):

To add to the current answers, you can get the failure message and the failure reason.  To do that, you can do this when presented with an NSError:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s\n%@\n%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, displayRegion, [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]];
```

This will create a 3 line string with the name of the method where the error occurred, the description of the error and a sentence explaining the error.

If more info is be supplied in the NSError, you can get the localizedRecoverySuggestion as well and add that to the message like so:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s\n%@\n%@\n%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, displayRegion, [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason], [error localizedRecoverySuggestion]];
```

Answer (score 1):

User error.userInfo, it returns dictionary ex:

```
 NSLog(@"%@",error.userInfo);
{
code = 101;
error = "invalid login parameters";
originalError = "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 \"The operation        couldn\U2019t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)\"";
temporary = 0;
}
```